# 'Unresolved type' from APK dependencies in an Android project with Maven

Tags: android, maven

I use [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/) (hereafter FMMR) in an Android app I'm developing in Eclipse. I'm trying to convert it to a Maven project, and this is the last dependency that's causing trouble.

Maven downloads FMMR correctly, but it isn't linked to "Maven Dependencies" in Eclipse, and importing it into a class gives me the error "The import wseemann cannot be resolved". Other dependencies work correctly.

FMMR is distributed as an APK; others are JAR.

The full POM is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.github.pconley</groupId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<artifactId>TestApp</artifactId>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.wseemann</groupId>
        <artifactId>FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>apk</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0-rc.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>21</platform>
                </sdk>
                <testCoverageFile>/data/data/com.github.pconley.TestApp/cache/test-coverage.ec</testCoverageFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Some notes:

- A complete, minimal sample project is [on Github](https://github.com/patrick-conley/Android-TestApp).
- I'm using m2e and m2e-android.
- I imported it into Android Studio and added the dependency in gradle: same problem.
- I tried using the jar I downloaded as a system-scoped dependency: this resolves the import errors but doesn't include FMMR in the compiled project.

Am I doing something wrong, or was the FMMR APK somehow built incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the packaging issue this morning, simply add the following line to your modules `build.gradle` file:

`compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.5`

Comment: Doesn't work in Maven/Eclipse, which doesn't support AAR. I should be moving my project to Gradle anyway, though.

Comment: I have used above mention line in my build.gradle file but still show me an error for FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever. Can not resolve "FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever".

Comment: Use version 1.0.5: `compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.5`